# ObjectMapper readValue invoked multiple times until a StackOverflowException is thrown

Tags: java, deserialization, json-deserialization, fasterxml

I am trying to build a custom deserializer class for my value class. But the ObjectMapper .readValue is being invoked multiple times until a StackOverflowException is being thrown. The following is an example only:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = UserDeserializer.class)
@Getter
public class User {
    private String name;
}

public class UserDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<User> {
    public UserDeserializer() {
        super(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return ctxt.readValue(p, User.class);
    }
}

public class UserDeserializerTest {
    @Test
    public void whenUserIsDeserializedFromJsonThenNameShouldEqualBob() {
        String = "{ \"name\" : \"bob\" }";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        User user = mapper.readValue(json, User.class);
        assertThat(user.getName).isEqualTo("bob");
    }
}
```

Maven Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The following StackOverflowException is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
...

// The following lines are repeated.

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.readValue(DeserializationContext.java:754)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.readValue(DeserializationContext.java:746)
    at example.UserDeserializer.deserialize(UserDeserializer.java:25)
    at example.UserDeserializer.deserialize(UserDeserializer.java:15)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried registering the deserializer via a module and removing the @JsonAnnotation and still throws the same exception:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("User Simple Module");
module.addDeserializer(User.class, new UserDeserializer());
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addModule(module);
mapper.readValue(json, User.class);
```

Then I tried creating a new ObjectMapper within my UserDeserializer and remove @JsonDeserialize from my User class and my test passes.

```
@Override
public User deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(p, User.class);
}
```

Whilst doing the above works, I want to register the deserializer on a per class basis using the @JsonDeserialize annotation rather than registering a global custom object mapper. There are reasons for me wanting it that way.

I tried other combinations of code, for example:

```
// Add the 'as' keyword to the annotation
@JsonDeserialise(using = UserDeserialize.class, as = User.class)

// Locally assigning a mapper from the JsonParser inside the UserDeserializer class
ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
mapper.readValue(p, User.class);

// Constructing a new JSON Parser inside the deserializer
ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
JsonFactory factory = mapper.getFactory();
JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(p.getText());
return (User) parser.readValueAs(handledType());

// Reading the Json into a Tree
ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) p.readValueAsTree();
return mapper.readValue(root.traverse(), User.class);
```

But reading the JSON into a Tree throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ObjectCodec defined for parser, needed for deserialization
    at example.User.main(User.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ObjectCodec defined for parser, needed for deserialization
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._codec(JsonParser.java:1565)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.readValueAsTree(JsonParser.java:1559)
    at example.UserDeserializer.deserialize(UserDeserializer.java:37)
    at example.UserDeserializer.deserialize(UserDeserializer.java:17)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3674)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1996)
    at example.UserDeserializer.deserialize(UserDeserializer.java:38)
    at example.UserDeserializer.deserialize(UserDeserializer.java:17)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3702)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2714)
    at example.User.main(User.java:36)
    ... 5 more
```

I also tried implementing the ContextualDeserializer inside my UserDeserializer but still get the same StackOverflowException as before:

```
private UserDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
    super(vc);
}

public JsonDeserializer<User> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
    return new UserDeserializer(ctxt.getContextualType().getRawClass());
}

@Override
public User deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    return (User) new ObjectMapper().readValue(p, handledType());
}
```

I hope this is just a bad case of a PEBKAC error and a solution is readily available with your help/guidance.

Kind regards

Comment: Just bear in mind that the non-repeating top of the stacktrace is irrelevant to the diagnostic.

Comment: Thanks Marko. I have removed the irrelevant portion of the stacktrace and left the most important bit.

Comment: Have you checked what goes on at `DeserializationContext.java:754`? You should be able to trace through the calls and see what makes it call back into itself.

Comment: @Gary don't know much about jackson, but doesn't this statement `ctxt.readValue(p, User.class);` in the deserialiser goes into infinite loop calling the same method again? What I mean is that you need to create a new user object and deserialise individual fields and set them up and return it.

Comment: What's actually the point of your custom deserializer?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with KDM, try this deserializer:

```
    public class UserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<User> {

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = p.readValueAsTree();
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(node.get("name").asText());
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marko - At line 754 it assigns the deser=example.UserDeserializer@771 (_valueClass="class example.User" and then invokes the deserialize method on the deserializer. Then the ctxt.readValue(p, User.class) then calls back to line 754, obviously ending in a vicious cycle.

Comment: @KDM - You are correct about the infinite loop. But I don't want to construct the concrete class within the deserializer. Ultimately I am trying to go for a generic deserializer that any object can be reconstructed from JSON. I was hoping the magic of the ObjectMapper would help me here, rather than trying to resolve an entire object via Reflection. I have custom annotations which I will be annotating my value classes with and the deserializer should treat them differently during construction phase.

Comment: @KDM - During the first cycle of constructing the object my annotations will be ignored via a DeserializationProblemHandler to say they will be handled later. Once the first stage of the deserialization has occurred, then using Reflection to help detect the annotations and construct the specialized classes to add to value class which implements a contract interface.

Comment: @Marko - To create a generic deserializer whereby a value class implements a common interface, and the deserializer will handle and treat custom annotations on the value class without having the know how the value class is constructed. The annotations refer to a specialized class that is then constructed and via Reflection assigned to the value class.